# Closing my model with Vue @click event handler not working

Tags: vuejs2, click, vue-component

I want the user to open and close a modal when click a button. To organize my code I use single file components.

In my single file button component `HamburgerButton.vue`, I have:

```
<template>
  <button @click.prevent="onClick"
>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path v-if="isOpen" d="M10"/>
      <path v-if="!isOpen" d="M0"/>
    </svg>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isOpen: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
     onClick (evt) {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
      this.$emit('click', evt) 
      component
     }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The registered button in my template:

```
<hamburger-button @click="onClicked"></hamburger-button>
```

My modal html:

```
<div :class="isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'" class="static">
 <!--Modal-->
</div>
```

In my `app.js` with my Vue instance I have:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#menu',
  data: {
    isOpen: false,
  },
  methods: {
   onClicked() {
    this.isOpen = true;
   }
  },
  components: {
    HamburgerButton,
  }
})
```

Everything is working except the modal is not closing when I press the button again?

I tried in my template the following:

```
<hamburger-button @click="onClicked = !onClicked"></hamburger-button>
```

But that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the **click** event to a parent component from HamburgerButton.
Something like this:

```
@click="onClick"
```

in a script:

```
...
methods: {
  onClick (evt) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    this.$emit('click', evt) // <--- passing the event to a parent component
  }
}
```

Comment: You call isOpen as a handler but this is a bool prop. You should call a handler (onClicked for instance) with something like this.isOpen=true in <hamburger-button @click="onClicked"></hamburger-button>

Comment: I fixed it and its working now.  I changed in my template `<hamburger-button @click="isOpen = !isOpen"></hamburger-button>` and from `app.css` I removed `methods: {
    onClicked() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    }
  },`. So because I am _emitting_ the event `onClick` from my component, I don't have to add it again in `app.css` where I create my new Vue instance? I just want to understand how this works exactly. Thanks

Comment: You embedded handler right into a template. It's useful for a short handler like isOpen = !isOpen but if your handler is more complicated then it is more convinient to extract a code to a handler function (like onClicked)